# TypeError: middleware is not a function in store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have my below code for combining store and reducer in react-redux. 
It works perfectly in my previous apps may be due to the react and react-redux version.

- But now I have setup fresh react project with the latest version but getting the error.

> TypeError: middleware is not a function

**Code :**

```
import 'rxjs'
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import promise from 'redux-promise-middleware'
import { createEpicMiddleware, combineEpics } from 'redux-observable'
// import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger'
import user, { userEpic } from './user/duck'
import userApp, { userAppEpic } from './user-app/duck'

import app from './app'

// Bundling Epics
const rootEpic = combineEpics(
  userEpic,
  userAppEpic
)

// Creating Bundled Epic
const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware()

// Define Middleware
const middleware = [
  thunk,
  promise(),
  epicMiddleware
]

// Define Reducers
const reducers = combineReducers({
  app,
  user,
  userApp,
  form: formReducer
})

// Create Store
export default createStore(reducers,
  applyMiddleware(...middleware))
epicMiddleware.run(rootEpic)
```

Can someone please help me to resolve the issue ?

Comment: remove the `()` here `promise()`, write it like this: `const middleware = [
  thunk,
  promise,
  epicMiddleware
]`

Comment: @MayankShukla You nailed it. Please post it as an answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [Doc](https://redux.js.org/api/applymiddleware#arguments):

> ...middleware (arguments): Functions that conform to the Redux
>   middleware API. Each middleware receives Store's dispatch and getState
>   functions as named arguments, and returns a function.

That means we need to pass functions to `applyMiddleware`. In your case, you are passing `promise()` instead of `promise` (function), that why it is failing with error:

> middleware is not a function

Write it like this:

```
const middleware = [ thunk, promise, epicMiddleware ];
```